# Get entire window height and width

Tags: jquery, window, height, width, detect

Would anyone be able to help me get the entire window size with jQuery or javascript? Currently I'm using this code:

```
<div id="winSize" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<script>
    var WindowsSize = function() {
        var h = $(window).outerHeight(),
            w = $(window).outerWidth();
        $("#winSize").html("<p>Width: " + w + "<br>Height: " + h + "</p>");
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){ WindowsSize(); });
    $(window).resize(function(){ WindowsSize(); });
</script>
```

This works fine but when I put my site on a server the height and width of the same size screen is different. When I go to a site such as "browser size.com" they detect the same size as what I see on my server. So what happens locally that makes it detect my window as a larger size?
For example:

Size on server - `Width: 1202 & Height: 551`
Size locally - `Width: 1336 & Height: 630`

They are slightly off which is making it hard for me to test responsiveness. any ideas?

Comment: The size of the window is detected purely on the client so running the code on your local machine or a server makes no difference. Could you please add a working example of the problem to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how Id go about adding a working example as the problem I'm having is when I detect it locally @RoryMcCrossan